# How can I handle stathreadattribute error on C#?

Tags: c#, mql5

I coded following C# code and create a "dll" from it and import in mql5 to run it. but after running it when I click inside dialog box.I confronted following error which I couldn't solve it:

```
"Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it"
```

Main C# code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;


namespace mainProg
{
    public static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]

        public static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form2());
        }
    }
}
```

and inside form2 I have:

```
   private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBox1.SelectAll();
        Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text);
    }
```

in MQL5 I have :

```
#import "mainProg.dll"

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Script program start function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnStart()
  {
 Program::Main();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, this problem appears because, you set set attribute `[STAThread]` in `Main` but the Form is managed by another thread that is initialized with `ApartmentState.MTA` by default.

Try to add this code on Form loading:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ApartmentState = System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA;
}
```

Should solve your problem.

**EDIT**

Now I saw that VS says "System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ApartmentState is obsolete". So, it's better to use:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
}
```

Comment: This leads to not recognizing "Threading" : "The name Threading does not exist in the current context".         private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ApartmentState = Threading.ApartmentState.STA;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
            backgroundWorker3.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

Comment: Yeah, try to use System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ApartmentState = System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA;. I updated my answer.

Comment: VS comments that "Thread.ApartmentState is obsolete. The apartment property has been depreciated. Use GetApartment, SetApartment or TryApartment instead." I compiled It anyway but again I have that problem.

Comment: I get this error: Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll. System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException occurred
  ErrorCode=-2147221040
  Message=Requested Clipboard operation did not succeed.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(Object data, Boolean copy, Int32 retryTimes, Int32 retryDelay)
  InnerException:

Comment: Ciao, try to set `retryTimes` to 2 in `Clipboard.SetDataObject(object data, bool copy, int retryTimes, int retryDelay)`

Comment: I add this code: Clipboard.SetDataObject(sender, true, 2, 1); But again the error occurs when I do left click on the text box. Actually when I do right click no problem happens.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't have the error anymore. Other issues was happened which I ask them by another threads.

Comment: Very happy to ear that! Have a nice day :)